# How to get dual citizenship in the EU?

Tags: eu, passport, dual-citizenship

I was born in Canada in 1970. My father was born in the Netherlands in 1948 and came to Canada when he was five. He holds a Canadian passport. My mother was born in Germany in 1949 and came over when she was 7. She holds a Canadian passport. **Is there anyway for me to obtain either a German or Netherlands passport as I would like to move to the EU?** The laws are seem extremely complicated and I everything I read says I cannot but I've met people who say they have been able to.

Comment: You need to find out whether your mother still held her Germany citizenship when you were born. That is, when did she naturalize? If she still was a German citizen when you were born, you have German citizenship. I think it's a lot less likely through your father (but I find the Dutch rules very complicated).

Comment: @mkennedy: German citizenship could not be passed from mother to child before 1975. But there is a special naturalization process for children born to German mothers before 1975 to get German citizenship now without renouncing their existing nationalities, if they can show proficiency in German or other connections to Germany.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. The German embassy in Canada doesn't make that distinction. Http://www.canada.diplo.de/kanada/en/02/citizenship/dual__citizenship__by__birth.html

Comment: With respect to the Dutch laws, you will have been a Dutch citizen at birth only if your father was naturalized *after* your birth, or if he was naturalized before his 21st birthday and independently from his own parents.  In that case, however, you most likely will have lost your Dutch nationality on your 28th birthday under the Dutch nationality law of (IIRC) 1985.  So you might be able to benefit from the Dutch "option" procedure for former Dutch nationals, but IIRC most of those require you be resident in the NL for at least one year.

Comment: @KristaH: To the OP: can you specify whether each of your parents naturalized before or after you were born?

Comment: This is unfortunately a good question which just never quite got enough information to provide a precise answer. With no further information from the OP, the question is unclear,